# Define a range using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

A simplified version of my problem is that on a different sheet called `Sheet2` I have data that I want to average:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet2!$A$1:Sheet2!$A$100)
```

Depending on where the code above is used I need to exchange column `A` for another letter, for example column `D`. To do this I have created a function:

```
=MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",4,1)
```

which will output `D`.

My problem is that instead of having to write:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet2!$D$1:Sheet2!$D$100)
```

I want to use:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet2!$MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",4,1)$1:Sheet2!$MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",4,1)$100)
```

but Excel does not accept this. How can I use functions next to `Sheet2!`?

Comment: This could be done with `INDIRECT`, but there may be a better way. What determines which column you want to use?

Comment: As I move to the right in my spreadsheet I want to increase by increments of 3, i.e. the first Average uses column A, second Average uses column D(=A+3), third Average uses column G (=A+3+3) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT :

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT ("Sheet2!$" & MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",4,1)&"$1:Sheet2!$" & MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",4,1)&"$100"))`

Comment: Thank you, Máté! This is *exactly* what I needed help with, I would never have figured out that its possible to use quotation marks in this manner. Thanks!!

Comment: There is a useful Excel function that simplifies and strengthens this approach, called ADDRESS(row, column,[abs],[format],[sheet]) that produces the cell reference as text.

For example, the output of ADDRESS(30,77,,,"Sheet2") is "Sheet2!$BY$30"

The benfits of using this include:
(1) formula that is short, simple, fast and understandable
(2) handling columns > "Z", and 
(3) coping with localisation issues.

So you can use INDIRECT( ADDRESS(.....) & ":" & ADDRESS(....) )

Answer (score 5):

OFFSET and INDIRECT are volatile we can use INDEX

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$100,0,4))
```

The `0` tells the INDEX to return all the rows and the `4` is the 4th column.  So all the rows from 1 to 100 in column 4 will be averaged.

As per your comments:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$100,0,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A:$A,0,(COLUMN()-1)*3))
```

Note that `OFFSET` is volatile and will increase the calculation load in your workbook